# how to insert mySQL command in a table row

Tags: mysql, oracle, insert

When i use the following command:

```
insert into history (id, command)  
values(2,'insert into show(id, moderator_ID, film_ID, time_length, adress, details) values(42,2,1,'123','123','123')');
```

It returns an error: missing comma. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **double quote** instead of **single quote** in second insert query

```
insert into history (id, command)  
values (2,'insert into show 
(id, moderator_ID, film_ID, time_length, adress, details) 
values (42,2,1,\"123\",\"123\",\"123\")');
```

Comment: It works, but i'm executing it in java, and the command value is used in a single variable. I tried "double-quoting" the whole command, but the maximum size for "double-quoting" is 30 characters. Any ideas?

Comment: just use `\` before double quote.

Comment: Here's the problem. in java, it is something like: `String sql="insert into history (id, command) values(2,'"+command+"')";`

Comment: This is correct. I didn't know you are passing parameters. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote like this :

```
INSERT INTO `history` ( `id` , `command` )
VALUES ( '2', 'insert into show(id, moderator_ID, film_ID, time_length, adress, details) values(42,2,1,''123'',''123'',''123'')');
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Returns: identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than letters and numbers...

Comment: what type of your field? try change to VARCHAR latin1_swedish